# Photo Gallery attached to Story - How to Create

Tags: blocks, media

I figured out a way to add a photo gallery to the bottom of a story using a custom content type for the photos, then creating a view with clickable thumbnails and saving it as a block. The problem is I can't reuse this for the next story. I would need to create yet another content type and another view. How can I set it up so I can post a different gallery to a different story?

Is there a module that might help with this?  I tried Views Galleriffic, but it doesn't seem to work as a block.  I couldn't find any way to make the gallery appear at the bottom of a story.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up add the images directly to the story with new fields so they could be shown as a gallery of thumbnails with a block.  I used a view with a grid and followed directions to create a contextual filter from this helpful post:
http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/easy-gallery-image-option-your-content-editors-drupal-7